# duality theorem for homogeneous system

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

hi there what is dual of a homogeneous system?

Primal:
$$\text{Max}\  cx $$

$$ Ax \le 0 $$

Dual : 
$$Min\ 0 $$

$$A^{T}y=c$$

$$y\ge 0$$

but what does it mean $Min\ 0$  in dual problem?

Comment: Do you know how to write the dual problem from its primal? If you do, you can see that the rhs of primal problem is 0. So, what happens to the objective function of your dual problem? If you don't know how to derive dual from primal, check out some of the many other questions on this site or online.

Comment: @EhsanK I already wrote the dual!!!!!!!!! I just dont know what means Min 0

Comment: Well, it means that your objective function is constant. You can think of problems that they don't have an objective function to optimize and just a feasible solution is enough. e.g. Sudoku is one of those.

Answer (score 1):

It means it is a feasibility problem.

Any feasible solution would make the objective function $0$, which is optimal.

If the dual is feasible, then clearly, $x=0$ is also an optimal solution to the primal by strong duality.